# What does the @type line do in tailwind.config.js file?

Tags: typescript

What does the following line found in tailwind.config.js when tailwindcss init is run do?

`/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */`

Comment: A quick search for that line of code found [this discussion in Tailwind's GitHub repo](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1077)...

Answer (score 0):

It helps with intellisence when you're filling in custom properties.